# If the function $f$ is a surjection, then the image of the preimage of a set under $f$ is that same set

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $f$ be a function from $A$ to $B$.
Let $f$ be a surjection onto $B$.

I strongly think that for any $Y \subset B$, then $f(f^-1(Y))=Y$.

I also think the surjection condition is necessary and no other condition is necessary (e.g. $f$ might not be an injection).

I have both the proof (hopefully correct) and the intuition.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. In fact, the converse also holds: if a function satisfies the condition you mentioned, it is surjective.

Comment: If f is not surjective, then $f^{-1}(Y}$ could be empty.

Comment: Good! Next try coming up with a preimage condition for injectivity!

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah nice intuition on why surjection is necessary!

Comment: @Laura thanks. Yes, I see clearly (and hopefully correct) that the preimage of the image of a set is that same set if the function is an injection (surjection is not required). I might try to prove it later...

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus I'm not gonna spoil your fun, so I reply with a really really really strong "maybe" and let you check it! ;) Surjection is not required (true). Also the comment by hamam has an injection version too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. For a surjective function $f:A\to B$ and a set $Y \subseteq B$, we have $f(f^{-1})(Y) = Y$.

Basically, the proof is about carefully writing what each concept means:

1. **Surjectivity of $f$:** By definition, being surjective means for every element $b \in B$, there exists at least one element $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. That is, every element in the codomain $B$ has a preimage in the domain $A$.
2. **Preimage:** The preimage of $Y$ under $f$, denoted by $f^{-1}(Y)$, is the set of all elements in the domain that map to elements in $A$. That is, $f^{-1}(Y) = \{a \in A:f(a) \in Y\}$.
3. **Image of the Preimage:** Now, we need to consider the image of $f^{-1}(Y)$ under $f$. This is the set of all elements in the codomain $B$ that are obtained by applying $f$ to elements in the preimage of $Y$. That is, $f(f^{-1}(Y)) = \{b \in B:\exists\,a \in f^{-1}(Y) \text{ such that } b = f(a)\}$.
4. **Showing Equality:** $f(f^{-1}(Y)) = Y$:

   - (a) $f(f^{-1}(Y)) \subseteq Y$: Consider any element $b \in f(f^{-1}(y))$. This means there exists an element $a \in f^{-1}(Y)$ such that $f(a) = b$. Since $a \in f^{-1}(Y)$, we know $f(a) \in Y$ by definition of the preimage. Therefore, $b \in Y$.
   - (b) $Y \subseteq f(f^{-1}(Y))$: Consider any element $b \in Y$. Since $f$ is surjective, there exists an element $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. This means $a \in f^{-1}(Y)$ by definition of the preimage. Therefore, $f(a)=b$ is in $f(f^{-1}(Y))$.

Comment: Yes that's exactly my proof. I was tempted to declare it obvious but when I tried to prove it rigorously I realized being a surjection is required. Even so I agonized a lot over the proof as I wasn't sure which parts to declare obvious and I was unable to write the proof in math-only notation and had to use a lot of natural language (like you do).

Comment: Certainly, it can be made much, much more concise. $\forall  b\in B\exists a\in A$ s.t. $f(a) = b$ describes that $f$ is surjective. But that's just notation. As your knowledge grows and your skill matures, results like this will be immediate, for they are but a direct consequence of the definitions. Writing proofs as if you were having a dialogue trying to explain it to your inner self is good practice.